# Lista crescente em c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int total = 10;
    char letra = '*';

    char *retorno;
    retorno = (char *) malloc(total + 1);

    for (int i=0; i<total; i++) {
      retorno[i] = letra;
      retorno[i+1] = '\0';

      printf("%s\n", retorno);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você tem o trecho do código que você fez? Tente explicar melhor a sua dúvida

Comment: é necessário fazer dois laço de repetição. Caso não for respondida a pergunta, quando eu chegar em casa eu mando a resposta

Comment: @AndreLacomski não precisa de dois laços para fazer isso

Answer (score 5):

É possível sim resolver esta questão com apenas um laço, apesar de requerer mais variáveis.
Segue uma possível solução:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int total = 10;
    char letra = '*';

    char *retorno;
    retorno = (char *) malloc(total + 1);

    for (int i=0; i<total; i++) {
      retorno[i] = letra;
      retorno[i+1] = '\0';

      printf("%s\n", retorno);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Já com dois laços, talvez seja mais fácil de entender:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int total = 10;
    char letra = '*';

    for (int i=0; i<total; i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<=i; j++){
        printf("%c", letra);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

> **peço desculpas se estraguei a pergunta (já que eu mesmo votei para fechá-la por não ser muito clara), mas os comentários não me
>   permitiram deixar passar..**

Comment: Boa! Realmente dá para fazer só com 1 laço. Nem me tinha ocorrido essa solução criativa, de ir concatenando apenas um char na mesma string.